# An estimate for $\ln(1+f(x))$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

A crucial skill for every aspiring analyst (like myself) is confidence in estimation - knowing when, where, and how to use tools like Big-and-little-O to gain quick upper bounds.  I'm trying to push myself to get better at it, but I'm still a little hesitant sometimes.  Here's an example: I need to determine if the following series converges uniformly

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2}\right)}{n}
$$

I'm pretty sure it does, and my reasoning is as follows: if $n>1$, $\sin^2(nx)/n^2<1$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, and hence we can use the Taylor series for $\ln(1+z)$ about $z=0$ to obtain the following:

$$
\left\vert\ln\left(1+\frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2}\right)\right\vert\leq\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{C}{n^4}\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
where $C$ is a constant independent of $x$.  Thus,

$$
\left|\,f_n(x)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{C}{n^5}
$$and since 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^5}\right)<\infty,
$$the series converges uniformly.

My question is: is $(\dagger)$ correct, and do I have the constant in the right place (or does it matter)?  I used the fact that $\ln(1+z)=z+O(z^2)$ to obtain $(\dagger)$.

Comment: @msh210 thanks for the copy editing...studying for quals has really cooked my noodle.

Comment: You're welcome, but my edit suggestion was accepted after you had made a clashing edit -- or so it seems -- so yours was lost.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering why a line disappeared...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use the simpler estimate, that says that $$\log(1+x)\leq x$$

Then $$\frac{1}{n}\log \left( {1 + \frac{{{{\sin }^2}nx}}{{{n^2}}}} \right) \leqslant \frac{{{{\sin }^2}nx}}{{{n^3}}}\leqslant \frac 1 {n^3}$$

One should always aim for the simple first!

**ADD** As per your estimate. First note that your function is always positive and periodic. Moreover, it is bounded. Since it has multiple roots, we know there is a maximum, and it will be an absolute "periodic" maxima. The derivative is $$\frac{{\sin 2nx}}{{n + {n^{ - 1}}{{\sin }^2}nx}}$$ which has roots at (choose $k=0,1$) so $2nx=0,\pi$. At $\pi/2n$ the maxima is $$\log\left(1+\frac 1 {n^2}\right)\leq\frac 1{n^2}$$

which is summable.

Comment: Ah! Now that is much simpler. Is my $(\dagger)$ still correct though, just out of curiosity?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. But as Peter says, try the simplest thing first, only if that doesn't work try the more complicated ones.

Comment: Another skill I need to work on =)  Thanks!